# Find out symbolic link target via command line

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, symbolic-link

Say that I setup a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /root/Public/mytextfile.txt /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt
```

is there a way to see what the target of `myothertextfile.txt` is using the command line?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use the `-f` flag to print the canonicalized version. For example:

```
readlink -f /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt
```

From `man readlink`:

```
-f, --canonicalize
      canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; all but the last component must exist
```

Comment: As suggested in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/330199/how-get-full-path-to-target-of-link), you may want to use `readlink -f`.

Comment: To get this working on Mac OS X, `brew install coreutils`. This installs basic gnu versions of commands prefixed with the letter `g`, i.e. `greadlink -f somefile`

Comment: with -f switch, command returns nothing in my case..

Comment: Using -f gave me the information that I wanted, i.e. resolving multiple symlinks and showing the end target.

Comment: on `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)` the manpages of readlink have a note saying  

"Note realpath(1) is the preferred command to use for canonicalization functionality."

Answer (score 24):

readlink is the command you want.  You should look at the man page for the command.  Because if you want to follow a chain of symbolic links to the actual file, then you need the -e or -f switch:

```
$ ln -s foooooo zipzip   # fooooo doesn't actually exist
$ ln -s zipzip zapzap

$ # Follows it, but doesn't let you know the file doesn't actually exist
$ readlink -f zapzap
/home/kbrandt/scrap/foooooo

$ # Follows it, but file not there
$ readlink -e zapzap

$ # Follows it, but just to the next symlink
$ readlink zapzap
zipzip
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the first answer, but this one is more complete and helpful.

Answer (score 6):

This will also work:

```
ls -l /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt
```

but `readlink` would be preferred for use in a script rather than parsing `ls`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to show the source and the destination of the link, try `stat -c%N files*`. E.g.

```
$ stat -c%N /dev/fd/*
‘/dev/fd/0’ -> ‘/dev/pts/4’
‘/dev/fd/1’ -> ‘/dev/pts/4’
```

It’s not good for parsing (use `readlink` for that), but it shows link name and destination, without the clutter of `ls -l`

`-c` can be written `--format` and `%N` means “quoted file name with dereference if symbolic link”.

Answer (score 3):

The `readlink` is a good thing, but GNU-specific and non cross platform. I used to write cross platform scripts for `/bin/sh`, therefore I'd use something like:

```
 ls -l /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt | awk '{print $NF}'
```

or:

```
 ls -l /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt | awk -F"-> " '{print $2}'
```

but these needs to be tested on different platforms. I think they'll work, but don't 100% sure for `ls` output format.

The result of `ls` can also be parsed within `bash` without depending on an external command like `awk`, `sed` or `perl`.

This `bash_realpath` function, resolves the final destination of a link (link→link→link→final):

```sh
bash_realpath() {
  # print the resolved path
  # @params
  # 1: the path to resolve
  # @return
  # >&1: the resolved link path

  local path="${1}"
  while [[ -L ${path} && "$(ls -l "${path}")" =~ -\>\ (.*) ]]
  do
    path="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  done
  echo "${path}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `readlink`, then parsing the result of `ls -l` could be done like this.

The normal result would be:

```
ls -l /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jan  1 12:00 /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt -> /root/Public/mytextfile.txt
```

So we want to replace everything before " -> " and the arrow included. We could use `sed` for this:

```
ls -l /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt | sed 's/^.* -> //'
/root/Public/mytextfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not accurate enough to give a simple answer as the one of brian-brazil:

```
readlink -f some_path
```

will indeed dereference **every symlink involved** in the path construct to the **final target** behind `some_path`.

But one level of cascading symlinks is just a particular case among others in a system, the general case being N levels of cascading symlinks. Look at the following on my system:

```
$ rwhich emacs
/usr/bin/emacs
 /etc/alternatives/emacs
  /usr/bin/emacs24-x
```

`rwhich` is my own recursive implementation of `which` that prints all of the intermediate cascading symlinks (to stderr) down to the final target (to stdout).

Then if I want to know what is:

- **the target of symlink** /usr/bin/emacs**, the obvious answer to me is `/etc/alternatives/emacs` as returned by:

  ```
  readlink $(which emacs)
  readlink /usr/bin/emacs
  ```
- **the *final* target behind cascading symlinks** /usr/bin/emacs, the answer shall be `/usr/bin/emacs24-x` as returned by:

  ```
  readlink -f $(which emacs)
  readlink -f /usr/bin/emacs
  rwhich emacs 2>/dev/null
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`ll` or `ls -l` should list the directory items, including your symbolic link and it's target

`cd -P /root/Public/myothertextfile.txt` (in your case) should point to the original path

Answer (score 0):

If you find the target of all links within a folder and its subfolder use the `find . -type l -ls` command with link type as follows:

```
me@local.localdomain:~/test$ find . -type l -ls
8601855888        0 lrwxr-xr-x    1 me           staff                   6 Jan 24 19:53 ./link -> target
```

If you want the target of a single, then `ls -l` should work:

```
me@local.localdomain:~/test$ ls -l 
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  staff  6 Jan 24 19:53 link -> target
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jan 24 19:53 target
```